# How to boost up my log statistic function?

Tags: node.js

I am doing a log scanning and statistic function running on node, due to the file size a bit large so it take quite long time to execute, so I try to boost it using promise pool. Here is the simple workflow of my function.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");

const filePathList = [
  ".\\log1.log",
  ".\\log2.log",
  ".\\log3.log",
  ".\\log4.log",
  ".\\log5.log",
  ".\\log6.log",
  ".\\log7.log",
  ".\\log8.log",
  ".\\log9.log",
  ".\\log10.log",
];

const poolSize = 10;
let promisePool = new Set();

const statistic = async () => {
  while (filePathList.length > 0) {
    while (promisePool.size < poolSize) {
      const filePath = filePathList.shift();

      const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
          const readLine = readline.createInterface({
            input: fileStream,
            crlfDelay: Infinity,
          });

          for await (const line of readLine) {
            // do something...
          }

          fileStream.destroy();
          promisePool.delete(promise);
          console.log(
            `${filePath} DONE!, remain promises: ${promisePool.size}`
          );

          resolve();
          analyzLog(threadIndex);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
      promisePool.add(promise);
    }
    await Promise.race(promisePool);
  }
  await Promise.all(promisePool);
};

(async () => {
  const start = Date.now();
  console.log(`Start statistic algorithm, timestamp: ${start}`);
  await statistic();
  const end = Date.now();
  console.log(`End statistic algorithm, timestamp: ${end}`);
  console.log(`It take ${(end - start) / 1000} sec`);
})();
```

As I know the fs is running outside node and it's multithreading. So I expecting it should be ten times fast. But no matter I run it with pool size 10 or 1. It take the similar time cost, so I think I didn't really doing the analyzing part concurrently. How can I make it work?

Comment: Even thought Node's Event Loop is multithreaded, your code is still single threaded. If "do something" is blocking too much, then the way you read IO (line by line) might finish long before.

I suggest using a package like @supercharge/promise-pool if you don't want to implement the pool yourself and elimitate the posibility or set up the node profiler to see where exactly it works/waits the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just only with `Promise.all`. Put each task into a single promise then push it into an array, then do `Promise.all(array)` so all tasks run parallel.

```js
const fs=require("fs");
const readline=require("readline");

const filePathList=[
  ".\\log1.log",
  ".\\log2.log",
  ".\\log3.log",
  ".\\log4.log",
  ".\\log5.log",
  ".\\log6.log",
  ".\\log7.log",
  ".\\log8.log",
  ".\\log9.log",
  ".\\log10.log",
];
// const poolSize=10;
const statistic=async () => {
  let promisePool=[];
  let fileLength=filePathList.length;
  filePathList.forEach((filePath) => {
    promisePool.push(new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let fileStream=fs.createReadStream(filePath);
      let readLine=readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity,
      });

      for await (let line of readLine) {
        // do something...
      }

      fileStream.destroy();
      console.log(
        `${filePath} DONE!, remain promises: ${--fileLength}`
      );
      resolve();
      // analyzLog(threadIndex);
    }));
  });
  return Promise.all(promisePool);
};

(async () => {
  const start=Date.now();
  console.log(`Start statistic algorithm, timestamp: ${new Date(start).toJSON()}`);
  await statistic();
  const end=Date.now();
  console.log(`End statistic algorithm, timestamp: ${new Date(end).toJSON()}`);
  console.log(`It take ${(end-start)/1000} sec`);
})();
```

Output:

```
Start statistic algorithm, timestamp: 2023-05-29T10:50:42.550Z
.\log3.log DONE!, remain promises: 9
.\log2.log DONE!, remain promises: 8
.\log1.log DONE!, remain promises: 7
.\log4.log DONE!, remain promises: 6
.\log6.log DONE!, remain promises: 5
.\log5.log DONE!, remain promises: 4
.\log8.log DONE!, remain promises: 3
.\log7.log DONE!, remain promises: 2
.\log10.log DONE!, remain promises: 1
.\log9.log DONE!, remain promises: 0
End statistic algorithm, timestamp: 2023-05-29T10:50:42.586Z
It take 0.036 sec
```